# Is there an open font that has the same length per letter as Amazon's Bookerly?

Tags: fonts

I'm writing in Google Docs and want to see where the line breaks would be for Amazon's Bookerly. Is there a free font available with the same horizontal length for every letter so that I could change to that font to see where my line breaks are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about Amazon's Bookerly, which is available for download from Amazon:

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/alexa/branding/echo-guidelines/identity-guidelines/typography

Comment: Thats pretty similar indeed. your pretty close to 4444

Comment: Be mindful, the included documentation states *These fonts are fully owned by Amazon, making their usage free to all internal product teams." so it's probably not allowed for anyone to just use them.